# When users click the Google+ sign-in button, how to avoid the button from popping-up?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-plus

By default, When user click the google+sign-up button, the login window will be Pop-up.

It is made by Javascript on html page.

I want to login by none Pop-up and hope that the login page appear on present.

I can not found solution on google document.

Is there any way?

Thank you.

Comment: You will either have to use a popup, or redirect the entire page. The authentication window will not work in an iframe.

Comment: How is way to redirect the entire page? If the relevant document, Could you show me the link to that?

Comment: Something like step three would work. https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/redirect-uri-flow